# Losing a bounty because OP doesn't check in

Tags: discussion, bounty

Is there a protocol for/anything you can do about a bounty expiring simply because the OP has not revisited the question?

I recently posted my first answer to a bounty question, for which I was pretty excited since the bounty q's are generally quite involved. I was proud of my answer and it was generously up-voted, but it seems the bounty expired before the OP saw my answer.

Comment: Others would know better, i think there is some sort of grace period, then the system awards the bounty if there is only one answer.

Comment: I see, the grace period just started like an hour ago, so I will update this post tomorrow night... Thank you @WillJagy

Comment: What, the 50-point bounty on the probability measure question? The points you get from upvotes on that question will probably measure more than the points from the bounty. (Yeah, weak pun, I know).

Comment: @Mr.Brooks or a _weak$*$ pun_??

Comment: Oh, I see, I had to reread the question details. Yes, I suppose.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is very little that can be done about a bounty setter who has abandoned their bounty. Note that the bounty setter *is* notified via the site notification system, and email, if possible, that their bounty is about to expire. Beyond that there is a fail-safe, of sorts.

First, the bounty period does not end at the end of the bounty period (huh?) but instead is automatically extended by 24 hours, a so-called grace period during which the bounty setter can still manually award the bounty. If, at the end of the grace period, the bounty setter *still* hasn't manually awarded the bounty then we get into possible "automatic awarding".

- If the bounty setter *accepted* an answer that was posted *after* the bounty was set, that answer is awarded with the bounty.
- Otherwise **half** of the bounty is awarded to the highest scored eligible answer, where an answer is eligible if it

  - was posted *after* the bounty was set;
  - has a score of at least +2; and
  - was posted by a user other that the bounty setter.

  If two or more answers fit all the criteria, the half-bounty will be awarded to the answer that was posted *first*.

(This, and more, information about the bounty system, can be found in the Meta Stack Exchange [bounty faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/214632).)

Comment: A sidenote: the bounty setter awarded bounty to charlestoncrabb about an hour after this question was posted.